# Bulk API upsert error for a Field type Location

Tags: custom-field, bulk-api, upsert, geolocation

I'm using the Bulk API v2 for upserting data into a CustomObject. When i try to upsert data without the CustomField Location, it works correctly, but when i add in the CSV the `Location__c` header, i'm getting this error:

`INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE:Unable to create/update fields: LastLocation__c. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.:LastLocation__c --`

this is my CustomField metadata xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>LastLocation__c</fullName>
    <businessStatus>Active</businessStatus>
    <displayLocationInDecimal>true</displayLocationInDecimal>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Last Location</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <scale>2</scale>
    <type>Location</type>
</CustomField>
```

What should i add to allow the `read/write` permission ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check field level security for Location__c field. (Check for the profile that you are using for insert operation)

Comment: On `Set Field-Level Security` section, i tried to select for all Profile, and i still get the error. I have other CustomField that are not a Location type, and it's work. Do you know if it's related to the Location type ? if we can't use that type on Bulk API perhaps ?

Comment: The Bulk API does not support any compound fields - Location or Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.
The issue was that i sent my CSV data with the column `LastLocation__c`, i had to use `LastLocation__latitude__s,LastLocation__longitude__s` to make it worked.